# Cleaning up when process goes down - WHY

Tags: c++

I'm writing c++ and have multiple objects I created during the life of the process, when the process goes down all its memory release to the OS so why should I clean up and release stuff ?

Comment: Have a look at the same question on [soft-eng](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/305930/if-i-need-to-use-a-piece-of-memory-throughout-the-lifespan-of-my-program-is-it).

Comment: There is way more than meets the eye. Especially with C++.

Comment: When I die, people will come and take away everything in my house, so why should I take out the trash while I'm alive?

Comment: It's much less of a problem with applications that run for a minute or two.  If something's being written that will run for hours, days, or even weeks, this becomes much more important.  If nothing else, this is always best practice.  EDIT: also even for a short running program, depending on how it's written, a large number of objects may be created that can eat through an unacceptable amount of memory...

Comment: Because destructors might do more than release memory and close file handles (or whatever else your OS does).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because it forces you to write clean reusable software. Let's imagine the situation where, say, you finish your game and all is fine even though you don't have clean-up code.

Now, given the huge success, you make a sequel and plan to reuse the code. But this time round you have a coop mode, a matchmaking lobby and a story mode. You realize you could simply delete the main `Game* object`, and create a new one with different parameters, when switching modes.

Then you realize: oops, although this would work nicely, all the unallocated memory prevents your from using this approach.

This is the pattern that always happen. It comes in different flavors. You want to write unit tests but between tests you need to clean-up everything. No clean-up: no way to have a clean test after the first one.

It looks like extra work, but it will pay off *a lot* in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of multiple reasons:

**Modularity**

- An application is usually a collection of modules
- Modules should have a well defined purpose, and should be reusable throughout your application, or even better, applications
- When writing a module, one should not assume how or when someone else is going to use it, so s/he should exercise best-practices and write it correctly

**Analysis**

When intentionally leaking resources, analyzing actual memory leaks
becomes a nearly impossible task. You can't differentiate modules that should free resources and those that shouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

Because what you think is wrong. In some cases indeed, you are right. If you instanciate objects like this: `A a;`, then A will be destroyed when getting outside its context. Now if you do `A *a = new A[12];` then 12 memory spaces the size of an instance of `A` are reserved. If you do nothing, at the end of the context, then `a` will be destroyed. But `a` is a pointer, so only the address of the array will be destroyed, the 12 spaces will still be allocated in memory and not accessible. They are lost for everyone.

And there are many other examples. Try to use Valgrind and you will see.

Now if your program gets more and more complicated, adding all these memory leaks could become a problem in the context of your own program. Of course when your program is over, the memory is given back to the OS, but that is definitely not a reason to tolerate memory leaks.

Comment: @Jeffrey Absolutely not. But A a; is ;-) - my bad

Comment: I understand the concept of memory leaks and sure the concept of freeing needed memory, but the question was about instances that leave all the time until program ends, in this case it won't be a memory leak and all a[12] memory will be returned to the OS ..

Answer (score 0):

There are many good reasons.

1) Some systems do not clean up after you.  Especially true in embedded systems, or systems running without an OS.

2) Usually an application main() is merely instantiating modules and subsystems that are reusable and should manage their own resources.  If main() is simply a minor function that instantiates some objects then runs the event loop, then your "application cleanup" code is not really application cleanup, but *module* cleanup.  A big difference.

3) Imagine your library was to run in someone else's code and you do not know how long it will be used, relative to the lifetime of the whole application.  If your code leaks, it will quickly be discarded as a low quality piece of code.

4) If it is difficult to clean up after yourself, it likely is an indicator of bugs in your design and memory / resource management.  By properly managing resources, you force a clean design and do not leave such management as an afterthought.  Therefore, I argue that *your code is less buggy when you design it to clean up when it is finished*.